# Build an insert statement in a new column using existing values in a db

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-update

I need help to build an insert statement using existing column values in DB . For eg

Existing table Student. columns as below

```
RollNo     Name       DOB         InsertStatement
1234       jason      11011990    NULL
1245       aaron      13071980    NULL
```

In the insert statement column I want the values as (may be using store procedure)`insert into mainDB (RollNo, Name, DOB) VALUES('1234','jason', '11011990');`

Require end result as below

```
RollNo     Name       DOB         InsertStatement
1234       jason      11011990    insert into mainDB (RollNo, Name, DOB) VALUES('1234','jason', '11011990');
1245       aaron      13071980    insert into mainDB (RollNo, Name, DOB) VALUES('1245','aaron', '13071980');
```

Can someone help me with the code

Store procedure but looks like my code isn't correct.

Comment: How about straight forward string concatenation?  I assume that `InsertStatement` column is text.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Do you want to store the decribed statement in the table? If yes: you should never store the same data twice. In this case you would have RollNo, Name and DOB twice. You can create this statement every time you need it.